# Обработка нажатия item_view в ViewPager для запуска/паузы MediaPlayer

Tags: android, mediaplayer

Хочу использовать нажатие на item_view в коде адаптера ViewPager для того, чтобы запускать, ставить на паузу аудиофайл. Однако не могу решить проблему снятия с паузы после нажатия на item_view во время воспроизведения. Повторное нажатие приводит к тому, что файл начинается сначала. Как исправить, подскажите пожалуйста

```
public class CustomSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    MediaPlayer mp;
    private Context ctx;
    ArrayList<String> pagesFiles;
    ArrayList<String> soundsFiles;
    String folderB;

    public CustomSwipeAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<String> pagesFiles, ArrayList<String> soundsFiles, String folderB) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.pagesFiles = pagesFiles;
        this.soundsFiles = soundsFiles;
        this.folderB = folderB;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pagesFiles.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view == object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        final String nameS = Uri.parse(soundsFiles.get(position)).getLastPathSegment();

        LayoutInflater layoutInflatter = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        assert layoutInflatter != null;
        View item_view = layoutInflatter.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout, container, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        File imgFile = new File(pagesFiles.get(position));
        if (imgFile.exists()) {
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
            imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            container.addView(item_view);
        }
        item_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String soundPath = String.valueOf(ctx.getExternalFilesDir(folderB));
                Uri souF = Uri.fromFile(new File(soundPath, nameS));
                if(mp == null){
                    mp = MyPlayer.getMediaPlayer();
//                    mp.setLooping(false);
                    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    try {
                        mp.setDataSource(ctx, souF);
                        mp.prepareAsync();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                                                 @Override
                                                 public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                                     mp.start();
                                                 }

                                             }
                    );}
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.seekTo(100);
                    mp.pause();
                } else {
                    mp.start();
                }
            }
        });

        return item_view;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }

}
```

Вот код класса:

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class MyPlayer {
    static MediaPlayer mp;

    public static MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer()
    {
        if (mp == null)
        {
            mp = new MediaPlayer();
        }

        return mp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно запомнить позицию:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
int pos = mp.getCurrentPosition();
mp.pause();
```

Далее:

```
mp.seekTo(pos);
mp.start();
```

Comment: Сергей, не понимаю как объект MediaPlayer может быть объявлен переменной. С проблемой разобрался, вы мне подсказали про использование seekTo() - она была лишней в коде.

Comment: но теперь другая проблема - не меняется аудиофайл при смене позиции - всё время воспроизводится первый файл....